# Widget minwidth for having N columns?

Tags: android, android-widget

What numbers should I put in widget provider xml minwidth/height to achieve 1, 2, 3, and 4 rows and columns?

From looking at other apps I found that people are using 72, 142, 220 and 294 dips but could not find any reference for it in the Google widget guidelines.

Are these numbers safe for all devices? Are they based on Google spec?

EDIT: corrected to 294 (was 290).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the authoritative spec here

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html

Minimum size in dip = (Number of cells * 74dip) - 2dip

72, 146, 220, 294

Comment: Warning, these formula is outdated. The new one since (don't remember Honeycomb or ICS) is 70 × n − 30

Comment: I remembered :), the new formula came with ICS (API 14)

Answer (score 9):

The official documentation can be found [here under "Determining a size for your widget"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy).

```
# of Cells   Available Size
1            40dp
2            110dp
3            180dp
4            250dp
…            …
n            70 × n − 30
```

These numbers are new though, they have been updated recently. The older documentation stated a different formula:

> To find your minimum width and height in density-independent pixels (dp), use
> this formula:
>
> **(number of cells * 74) - 2**
>
> Following this formula, you
> should use 72 dp for a height of one cell, 294 dp and for a width of
> four cells.

[*source*](http://web.archive.org/web/20110428104419/http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Which is in line with values like 72. The other values seem somewhat random to me.

Comment: Thanks. These are the numbers I used originally but they seems to be incorrect. Specifying 250 on RAZR MAXX results in only 3 rows/columns, not 4. Also, all the apps I have seen use 290 for 4 rows/columns. My question is where the 290 came from?

Comment: (290 is a typo, should be 294). Here is a Google example of a 4x1 widget. It uses 294 x 72.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData

Comment: @user1139880 294 for 4 cells is the old formula that I posted, `(4*74)-2 = 294`. Same with `(1*74)-2 = 72` for one cell. I never worked with these new numbers though, not sure what that is all about.

Comment: Thanks @alextsc. It's all started when my app got only 3 cells for 250dip on RAZR MAXX, instead of 4 on all other devices. I plan to use the old numbers as all the other apps I have seen. If you will edit your answer to reflect these numbers I will mark it as the correct one.